# How to make working Allure when running tests in parallel using Pytest?

Tags: selenium, pytest, allure, xdist

The problem is that I'm using Pytest+Selenium+Allure+Selenoid+Testrail.
When tests are running in 1 thread, all is working fine.

But when I try to run parallel tests execution:

- pytest-xdist: Allure creates an empty report
- pytest-parallel: does not creates any reports in alluredir

The question: is there any way to make Allure working with parallel test execution using Pytest?

Comment: The problem was in DNS/VPN settings in the office network